# Magento 2: How to get existing mini cart product's category ID in checkout_cart_product_add_before observer?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, mini-cart

I am trying with following code.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer){ 
    $quoteId = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItems();
    $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->load($quoteId);
    $cartItemsList=$quote->getAllItems();   
    $this->_logger->info($cartItemsList);           
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, please don't use object manager in production code.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer){
    $quoteId = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
    $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->load($quoteId);
    $cartItemsList = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItemsList as $item){
        $productid = $item->getProductId();
        $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
        $categoriesIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $this->_logger->info($categoriesIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting following error in log.
main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Warning: PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 296

Comment: try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and i have tested my code it's working.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer){
    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/categoriesIds.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $cartItemsList = $quote->getAllItems();
    
    foreach ($cartItemsList as $item) {
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $categoriesIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $logger->info(print_r($categoriesIds, true));
    }
}
```

See my output.

[image]

If any query let me know.

**`THANKS.`**